# Variable 'email' should not be initialized on declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I'm trying to create a random generator for emails in my cypress code

this is my exemple :

```
export function userEmail(): string {
  let email = "",
    domainName = "",
    possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (let i = 0; i < tabSize9; i++)
    email += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  domainName += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return `${email}@${domainName}.com`;
}
```

it's working for me as well , but the problem is when i lunch my eslint script , it says to me that the variable email should not be initialized on declaration , even my domainName variable

Any help !

thank you in advance

Comment: What is your eslint `init-declarations` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split the declarations on 3 different lines

```
let email = "";
let domainName = "";
let possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
```

Comment: easey to do that

Answer (score 1):

You try this :

```js
export function userEmail(): string {
 const possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
 let email = "";
 let domainName = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < tabSize9; i++){
    email += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    domainName += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return `${email}@${domainName}.com`;
}
```

Comment: Note: This is also different from the code in the question in that it adds braces around the for loop. In the original code, the domainName would only be one character long. I also assume that that is the intended functionality but wanted to point out the difference regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use faker.js to generate random emails.

1. Install faker js with `npm install @faker-js/faker --save-dev`
2. In order to have faker working properly, you need to check if these compilerOptions are set correctly in your tsconfig file:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  }
}
```

3. In your test

```js
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';

export function userEmail(): string {
  return faker.internet.email();
}
```

You can play around with what type of random emails you want to generate. Like if you want to keep the domain name or first, the last name constant etc. Refer [Faker Js Document](https://fakerjs.dev/api/internet.html#email)

```js
faker.internet.email(firstName?: string, lastName?: string, provider?: string, options?: {
  allowSpecialCharacters: boolean
} = { allowSpecialCharacters: false }): string
faker.internet.email() // => "Larry_Ratke85@yahoo.com"
faker.internet.email() // 'Kassandra4@hotmail.com'
faker.internet.email('Jeanne', 'Doe') // 'Jeanne63@yahoo.com'
faker.internet.email('Jeanne', 'Doe', 'example.fakerjs.dev') // 'Jeanne_Doe88@example.fakerjs.dev'
faker.internet.email('Jeanne', 'Doe', 'example.fakerjs.dev', { allowSpecialCharacters: true }) // 'Jeanne%Doe88@example.fakerjs.dev'
```